# Open URL in an image

Tags: url, openurl

I would like to open a url when the user clicks on an image. For example, I want to open Facebook or twitter when the user clicks on the Facebook or twitter icon.  How can i do it?

Comment: Please expand you question little bit - it is not clear where and how do you want to do that. And add some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, just surround `<img>` tag with `<a>` and `</a>`, for instance:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="image.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in an anchor tag.

```
<a href =www.example.com><img src="your image" /></a>
```